# ExpandableListView adding groups inside another group

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am having an ExpandableListView inside a fragment which is part of a tab. 
So inside - onCreateView(...) of fragment class I do :

```
ExpandableListView expandableList = (ExpandableListView) view
        .findViewById(R.id.groupList);
parent.add(getString(Group1));
parent.add(getString(Group2));
ArrayList<MyObject> groupList1 = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
ArrayList<MyObject> groupList2 = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
childs.add(groupList1);
childs.add(groupList2);
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), parent,
        childs);
```

Now when I open both the groups and then switch to tab by doing :

```
 transaction.replace(R.id.realtabcontent, new MyFragment(),
                "MyFragment");
```

And again come back to this tab by doing the same, the last group gets added with groups with child item.

Note : This only happens when we switch tab using replace. When we open for the first time launching the activity this works fine.

Kindly let me know what might be going wrong here. Let me know if I need to provide more code. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The issue got resolved. Although not sure about the way is appropriate or not. onCreateView(..) of fragment was being called multiple times on replace. So put a static counter so that is is called only once. Also after the replace I did a transaction.hide and transaction.show. This resolved my issue :)